# Building a financial app with Django

Tags: python, django, open-source

I'm building an app for a small business so I've to work with currencies, decimal numbers, etc... My goal is to create something like pulseapp.com.

I've searched for opensource projects to look and the only thing I had found was [django-cashflow](http://code.google.com/p/django-cashflow/). This app uses python-money.

I've read some of the code and the ways it's coded seems a bit weird to me and it's not fully complete.

Is the app worth to take a deep look?

Does anyone know about another similar app?

Is the task difficult or a begginer like me could find a way to code it himself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started to use python-money in an application a couple years ago, but had to abandon it due to some problem.  I apologize for forgetting the exact problem, but I do remember for our use case it didn't make sense anyway... we just needed decimal fields.

I'd also be wary of django-cashflow not having any activity for 2 years, although the project is small enough it should be easy enough to fix any problems yourself.

For existing Django accounting apps I would suggest enhancing, or at least looking at, [minibooks](https://secure.caktusgroup.com/projects/minibooks/wiki). NOTE: the license is AGPL v3 which could make it unusable for your environment.

Another road to travel would be to investigate porting [OpenERP](http://www.openerp.com/) (also GPL IIRC) from Python/GTK to Django.  [Tryton](http://www.tryton.org/en/) might also be a starting point, it's GPL3 and IIRC a fork of OpenERP.

Comment: Thanks for the links!, I'll take a better and deeper look at them. I think that they're too much for the things I want to do(income-expenses-balance) but I'll try to find the parts of my interest.

Comment: OpenERP and Tryton are very complex, but minibooks is probably very close to what you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with currencies, you might look to satchmo's codebase. http://www.satchmoproject.com/  They're the current front-runner in Django e-commerce. I'm sure they have money modules.

Comment: You're right, you made me remind that I've a book called "Beginning E-commerce with Django". I'll search trough the book to find how the autor handles the accounting.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have something you might be interested:

[Tryton with Django](http://code.google.com/p/tryton/wiki/TrytonDjango)

Answer (score 1):

I've written a framework to help speed up the development of customised commerce aspects of django sites: [Rollyourown shopping](http://code.google.com/p/rollyourown/wiki/RollyourownShopping).

It lets your write your models yourself, and uses a declarative syntax to define a summary class, which handles calculating totals, caching and formatting values etc. It's pretty fast for my use cases, and very flexible: I've used it for online stores, billing for consulting-services and auction sites :-)

The current version works fine, but I'll be releasing a '1.0' version later this month as I decide on the final (stable) API details (names etc) and maybe some external reviews.